# Add borders and change color of blank cells in a table

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a table of tournament results from my bass club in Google Sheets (see the TX Summary tab in https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPH2lKDtDqdjnghbYS3kWtXb3IGmunXao1JuWdi5SgM/edit?usp=sharing).  The table is the result of a QUERY function grouped by member and pivoted by event number.  When a club member doesn't participate in a particular tournament, the corresponding cell in the table is blank.

[Click here for an image of the desired table state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaThs.jpg)

I have a Google script (see below) that I copied and modified, which changes borders and colors of cells on the active sheet.  It works great if the QUERY  result has values populated in all cells.  I'm able to change blank cells outside the table to #0066cc with no borders.  I'm able to change cells containing a value within the table area to #dbdbdb with borders on all sides.

What I'm struggling with is when the QUERY result contains BLANK cells.  For those situtations, I want to add borders and change the color to #aaaaaa.  Currently, the script is coloring blank cells within the table #0066cc and not adding borders (falling through to the else statement).  I end up with a table that looks like I've been playing BREAKOUT (remember that one?).  I've tried multiple variations of comparisons in the second if statement (I thought == "" or === "" would do it) in an attempt to alter those cells, but I just can't seem to get it to work.  I know I'm probably missing something really, really simple, but after looking at this till my eyes bleed, I can't see the forest for the trees.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Duke Bevard

```
function summaryBorders() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns());
var cells = doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds();
range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] !== "") {
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      cells[i][j] = "#dbdbdb";
      if (values[i][j] == "" && j >=2 && j<15) {
        range.getCell(i + 1,j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
        cells[i][j] = "#aaaaaa";
        }
    } else {
      cells[i][j] = "#0066cc";
    }
  }  
}
doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns()).setBackgrounds(cells);
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are unable to get blank cells within you data range to be gray is because the following code has a bug:

```
if (values[i][j] !== "") {                  // This block doesn't run when you have a blank cell
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      cells[i][j] = "#dbdbdb";
      if (values[i][j] == "" && j >=2 && j<15) {            // this if statement is never called I.e. this block is skipped over when the cell is empty
        range.getCell(i + 1,j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
        cells[i][j] = "#aaaaaa";
        }
    } else {
      cells[i][j] = "#0066cc";
    }
```

The second if statement is never executed. Because it is inside the first of block, which is never executed when a empty cell is encountered. 
To make it work properly you will have to do something like this

```
if (values[i][j] !== "") {
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      cells[i][j] = "#dbdbdb";
   } else if (values[i][j] == "" && j >=2 && j<15) {
        range.getCell(i + 1,j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
        cells[i][j] = "#aaaaaa";
    } else {
      cells[i][j] = "#0066cc";
    }
```

For more details on if else you can have look at [tutorial here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp)

Comment: Thanks Jack!  That solved the issue.  Now I just need to bracket the range that the dark gray is only applied to blanks within the the table range.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

this appears to work- The reason why it wasn't working is because there is a difference between blank and zero cells. blank meaning a cell that has a "space in it" zero cells are like not active. So i changed it to look for 0 or blank, also I removed the small part " && j >=2 && j<15" for testing- you will want to add it back in.

```js
function summaryBorders() {
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns());
var cells = doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns()).getBackgrounds();
range.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] !== "") {
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      cells[i][j] = "#dbdbdb"; }
      if (values[i][j] = 0 || values[i][j] == "") {
        range.getCell(i + 1,j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
        cells[i][j] = "#aaaaaa";
        }
     else {
      cells[i][j] = "#0066cc";
    }
  }  
}
doc.getRange(1, 1, doc.getMaxRows(), doc.getMaxColumns()).setBackgrounds(cells);
}
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the responses.  I've tried the code and they aren't accomplishing what I'm trying to achieve.  That may be partly my fault, as I posted a screenshot of the table resulting from the code I submitted, not the desired state, and that's on me for sure.  I went in an altered the table manually using the border tool and colored the blank cells dark gray using the fill tool, and reposted the screenshot.

If you could take another look and let me know if what I'm trying to achieve is doable, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks, Duke

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting your range.

I've used this code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 // Returns the active range
 var range = sheet.getRange(3,3,3,4);
  Logger.log(range.getLastRow())
 var cells = sheet.getRange(3,3,3,4).getBackgrounds();

  var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
    if (values[i][j] !== "") {
      range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
      cells[i][j] = "#dbdbdb";
      if (values[i][j] == "" && j >=2 && j<15) {
        range.getCell(i + 1,j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true)
        cells[i][j] = "#aaaaaa";
        }
    } else {
      cells[i][j] = "#0066cc";
    }
  }  
}
  sheet.getRange(3,3,3,4).setBackgrounds(cells);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Hope this helps.